# What is the file "-", and why can only stat see it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 12.  When I type into my terminal `stat -`, I get the following output:

```
  File: ‘-’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   character special file
Device: ch/12d  Inode: 3           Links: 1     Device type: 88,0
Access: (0620/crw--w----)  Uid: ( 1000/   anotherguy)   Gid: (    5/     tty)
Access: 2014-12-19 18:04:40.454800919 -0600
Modify: 2014-12-19 18:04:40.454800919 -0600
Change: 2014-12-19 16:55:48.454800919 -0600
 Birth: -
```

There's no such file I can see with the `ls` function, and it doesn't matter what directory I'm in, `stat` still sees this "file".  However, replacing `-` with `./-` gives "no such file or directory".

This strange behavior is similar to the `cd` function's use of the "-" option, essentially treating the option as an argument, making it the previous directory.

Comment: `character special file` with a GID of `tty` are clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` is not a filename--different programs will handle it differently. For example, cd interprets `-` to mean cd $OLDPWD, while many other programs treat `-` to mean `/dev/stdout` ([slightly more info from selected answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename)).

If you try, `stat -f -`, you'll get the following error:

```
stat: using ‘-’ to denote standard input does not work in file system mode
```

So then, what is this, `stat -`? I tested it on several distributions of Linux as well as Mac OS X. `stat -` is equivalent to `stat $(tty)`, and appears to be a reference to the character device file associated with your terminal session.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.  I recall reading that many programs use the - for standard input.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not in its manual page, `stat` uses the convention that `-` as a file name signifies standard input (or sometimes standard output), so you will find that the following two commands are equivalent:

```
stat ExistingFile
stat - < ExistingFile
```

Comment: intersting.  I hadn't thought to do that, but you're right, it gives the same result.